# ValueError when attempting to create dataframe with OneHotEncoder results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have recently started learning python to develop a predictive model for a research project using machine learning methods. I have used OneHotEncoder to encode all the categorical variables in my dataset

```py
    # Encode categorical data with oneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
    Z = ohe.fit_transform(Z)
```

I now want to create a dataframe with the results from the OneHotEncoder. I want the dataframe columns to be the new categories that resulted from the encoding, that is why I am using the **categories_** attribute. When running the following line of code:

```py
    ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(Z, columns=ohe.categories_)
```

I get the error: **ValueError: all arrays must be same length**

I understand that the arrays being referred to in the error message are the arrays of categories, each of which has a different length depending on the number of categories it contains, but am not sure what the correct way of creating a dataframe with the new categories as columns is (when there are multiple features).

I tried to do this with a small dataset that contained one feature only and it worked:

```py
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
    df = pd.DataFrame(['Male', 'Female', 'Female'])
    results = ohe.fit_transform(df)

    ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=ohe.categories_)
    ohe_df.head()
    
        Female  Male
    0   0.0     1.0
    1   1.0     0.0
    2   1.0     0.0
```

So how do I do the same for my large dataset with numerous features.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

As requested, I have come up with a MWE to demonstrate how it is not working:

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    # create dataframe 
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Male', 'Yes', 'Forceps'], ['Female', 'No', 'Forceps and ventouse'],
                                 ['Female','missing','None'], ['Male','Yes','Ventouse']]), 
                      columns=['gender', 'diabetes', 'assistance'])
    
    df.head()
    
    # encode categorical data 
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
    results = ohe.fit_transform(df)
    print(results)
```

By this step, I have created a dataframe of categorical data and encoded it. I now want to create another dataframe such that the columns of the new dataframe are the categories created by the OneHotEncoder and rows are the encoded data. To do this I tried two things:

```py
    ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=np.concatenate(ohe.categories_))
```

And I tried:

```py
    ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=ohe.get_feature_names(input_features=df.columns))
```

Which both resulted in the error:
**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 9)**

Comment: Can you provide access or generate a dataset where this doesn't work?

Comment: I can't provide access to the dataset but I will try to generate a dataset now demonstrating the error I get.

Comment: @ScottBoston I've created a small example to demonstrate the errors I am getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Male', 'Yes', 'Forceps'], ['Female', 'No', 'Forceps and ventouse'],
                            ['Female','missing','None'], ['Male','Yes','Ventouse']]), 
                    columns=['gender', 'diabetes', 'assistance'])

df.head()

# encode categorical data 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
results = ohe.fit_transform(df)
df_results = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(results)
df_results.columns = ohe.get_feature_names(df.columns)
df_results
```

Output:

```
   gender_Female  gender_Male  diabetes_No  diabetes_Yes  diabetes_missing  assistance_Forceps  assistance_Forceps and ventouse  assistance_None  assistance_Ventouse
0            0.0          1.0          0.0           1.0               0.0                 1.0                              0.0              0.0                  0.0
1            1.0          0.0          1.0           0.0               0.0                 0.0                              1.0              0.0                  0.0
2            1.0          0.0          0.0           0.0               1.0                 0.0                              0.0              1.0                  0.0
3            0.0          1.0          0.0           1.0               0.0                 0.0                              0.0              0.0                  1.0
```

Note, the output of `ohe.fit_transform(df)` is a sparse matrix.

```
print(type(results))
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

You can convert this to a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix`.  Then, we can use `ohe.get_feature_names` and passing the original dataframe columns to name your columns in the results dataframe, df_results.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you for the clear explanation and code.

Answer (score 3):

`ohe.categories_` is a list of arrays, one array for each feature.  You need to flatten that into a 1D list/array for `pd.DataFrame`, e.g. with `np.concatenate(ohe.categories_)`.

But probably better, use the builtin method `get_feature_names`.

Comment: Do you mean to try and replace categories_ with get_feature_names? I tried running ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(Z, columns=ohe.get_feature_names(obj_df.columns[1:-1])) where obj_fd is my dataframe with categorical features, but I got the error message "Shape of passed values is (13858, 1), indices imply (13858, 193)".

Comment: I get the same error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (13858, 1), indices imply (13858, 193)
when running the command: 
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(Z, columns=np.concatenate(ohe.categories_))

Comment: @sums22 I assume `Z` is the same as `result` above?  At least the latter (using `np.concatenate`) worked on my toy example.  Maybe you can provide a MWE?

Comment: Yes in the code above Z is an array of categorical features, I then overrode it with the results from the OneHotEncoder.

Comment: I have created a MWE, please take a look and let me know what can be improved.

Comment: @sums22, Scott beat me to it after the MWE:  your problem is primarily that ohe is a sparse array, so you either need to explicitly instantiate the dataframe as from sparse, or densify.  Your `get_feature_names` approach fails because you haven't called the function: add `()` or better `(input_features=df.columns)`.

Comment: Thank you @BenReiniger, you've helped a lot. I will edit my question and add () to the get_features_names method so it does not take away from the primary problem which is the sparse array.